# Button Getting Populating Some Other Cell in UITableViewCell using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created `UITableview` Programmatically and Populated array values dynamically. Here My Problem is, I created a `UIButton` Programmatically for zeroth row, It created well but When I am Scrolling the tableview button is Populating some other cells also. I don't Know how to solve that issue in my tableview. I want a `UIButton` on Only Zeroth index of the cell. I have tried the below code..

```
- (IBAction)MoreBttn:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults1 = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults1 setObject:amenties forKey:@"FACILITIES"];
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    amentiestableview=[[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:screenRect style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    amentiestableview.delegate=self;
    amentiestableview.dataSource=self;
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,10,20,10);
    CGRect tableframe=amentiestableview.frame;

    amentiestableview.frame=UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(tableframe,insets);

   [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:amentiestableview];

}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [amenties count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"facilities";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 0) {
        UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        float X_Co = self.tableView.frame.size.width - 60;
        [b setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 0.0, 60, 45)];
        [b setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [b addTarget:self
              action:@selector(hidetableview:)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearpink.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:b];
    }
    else{

    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[amenties objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
-(void)hidetableview:(UIButton*)sender
{
    amentiestableview.hidden=YES;

}
```

[image: Snapshot of my output]

Answer (score 2):

The cell is being re-used, so the button appear on other cells. Try to update `cellForRow` method as follows:

```
 if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


                UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                float X_Co = self.tableView.frame.size.width - 60;
                [b setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 0.0, 60, 45)];
                [b setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                [b addTarget:self
                      action:@selector(hidetableview:)
            forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearpink.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
               [cell addSubview:b];
        }

        if(indexPath.row == 0) {
                b.hidden = false
            }
            else{
                 b.hidden = true
}
```

Comment: [b removeFromSuperView]; crashing the APP ..'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIButton removeFromSuperView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffdb88ae9b0'

Comment: @ShubamGupta Try to use `b.hidden = true`.

Comment: I tried Both the condition,But still buttons is being populating some other cells also..

Comment: @ShubamGupta, Please check the updated answer. Now I have created the button only once (in cell = nil condition). Button's visibility is now handling in if-else condition.

Comment: I have tried above code,but still facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

We are recycling the cells by using the method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier. And you should recycle cells because the allocation of views need a lot of resources

Please try the below code

```
 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

      if (cell == nil) {
                    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


                }

                if(indexPath.row == 0) {
                        UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
                        float X_Co = self.tableView.frame.size.width - 60;
                        [b setFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, 0.0, 60, 45)];
                        [b setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                        [b addTarget:self
                              action:@selector(hidetableview:)
                    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                        [b setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"clearpink.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                        b.tag = 1010

                       [cell addSubview:b];
                    }
                    else{
    cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1010).removeFromSuperview()
        }
```

Comment: cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1010).removeFromSuperview() showing error

Comment: I cleared that error,but  still same issue, button is coming some other cells